# Usar input select para autocompletar campos en PHP, Mysql, Ajax, Jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Autocompletado de Mutiples campos Usando jQuery , Ajax , PHP y MySQL</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
            $("#codigo").autocomplete({
                source: "productos.php",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('#codigo').val(ui.item.codigo);
                    $('#descripcion').val(ui.item.descripcion);
                    $('#precio').val(ui.item.precio);
                    $('#id_producto').val(ui.item.id_producto);
                 }
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  Codigo:  <input id="codigo">
  Producto: <input id="descripcion" readonly>
  Precio: <input id="precio" readonly>
  <input type="hidden" id="id_producto">
  <p>Ingresa 00</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y me trae por medio de una función el archivo -productos.php-

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "basededatos");

$return_arr = array();
/* Si la conexión a la base de datos , ejecuta instrucción SQL. */
if ($con)
{
    $fetch = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM productos where codigo_producto like '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_GET['term'])) . "%' LIMIT 0 ,50"); 

    /* Recuperar y almacenar en conjunto los resultados de la consulta.*/
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        $id_producto=$row['id_producto'];
        $precio=number_format($row['precio_venta'],2,".","");
        $row_array['value'] = $row['codigo_producto']." | ".$row['nombre_producto'];
        $row_array['id_producto']=$row['id_producto'];
        $row_array['codigo']=$row['codigo_producto'];
        $row_array['descripcion']=$row['nombre_producto'];
        $row_array['precio']=$precio;
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
}

/* Cierra la conexión. */
mysqli_close($con);

/* Codifica el resultado del array en JSON. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);

}
?>
```

Hasta alli todo funciona muy bien, si yo coloco el codigo del producto el me trae los datos y luego cuando elijo un producto me rellena los otros dos campos automaticamente.

El problema es que estoy buscando que ese input código sea un select y me traiga de mi base de datos los productos que ya están registrados por default y no necesariamente tenga yo que escribirlo sino que solo tenga que seleccionar el producto y ya me rellene los otros dos campos con la información que ya tengo.

De que forma podría hacerlo? muchas gracias quedo atento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues se me ocurre, que podrías rellenar los options con un ajax que te traiga todos los valores del código, y tus otros 2 campos...

Aquí tienes el HTML de ejemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(cargarCodigos);
        $(document).ready(initialEvents);

        function cargarCodigos() {
            $.ajax("Productos.php")
                .done(function (data) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(data); // Convertimos el json a objeto de JavaScript.
                    var sel = $('#codigo');
                    sel.empty();
                    sel.append('<option value="-1">Seleccione un código</option>'); // Insertamos un registro para que seleccionen.
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        sel.append('<option value="' + response[i].codigo + '" precio="' + response[i].precio +
                            '" id_producto="' + response[i].id_producto + '" descProducto="' + response[i].descripcion + '">' +
                            response[i].codigo + '</option>'); // Agregamos los distintos registros.
                    }
                });
        }

        function initialEvents() {
            $('#codigo').on('change', function () { // Agregamos el evento change al select.
                var SelectedOption = $($('#codigo option:selected')[0]); // Obtenemos el elemento seleccionado.
                var descripcion = SelectedOption.attr('descProducto');
                var precio = SelectedOption.attr('precio');
                var id_producto = SelectedOption.attr('id_producto');
                $('#descripcion').val(descripcion);
                $('#precio').val(precio);
                $('#id_producto').val(id_producto);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        Codigo: <select id="codigo"></select>
        Producto: <input type="text" id="descripcion" readonly>
        Precio: <input type="text" id="precio" readonly>
        <input type="hidden" id="id_producto">
        <p>Ingresa 00</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te ayude, un saludo!!

Comment: Buenas @Rubén Espada, tu respuesta es util pero aun sigue sin funcionarme, hice lo mismo tal cual, y cambio el nombre de mi archivo productos.php por cargarCodigos.php y aun asi no hace nada, solo salen los input y ya. de todas formas muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Te dice algo en la consola? Mira la parte de Network para ver si está haciendo bien la petición, sino, dame un rato y hago un pequeño ejemplo y lo intento subir

Comment: Ahí tienes, creo que lo que realmente faltaba antes, es pasar el json a objeto de JavaScript... Pero ese es el ejemplo completo que acabo de probar (en el php no he hecho cambios, sólo los propios para mi bbdd).
Espero así te ayude @estrada

Comment: Hola, listo @Rubén Espada, ya me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada compañero, cualquier cosa andamos por aquí jejeje :)